# Nginx install module from source, after it been installed from repository

Tags: nginx

I have installed the mainline version of Nginx using the Lauchpad PPA Respositiy on ubuntu 16.04 LTS a few week ago, using: add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/development

I would like to install a module into it, however, it needs to be installed from source and is not available using apt-get.

If I download the same version of Nginx that is installed on my server and install the module from source.

Will this affect what has already been installed, or will it work s before but with the new module?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have decided to rebuild it all of source, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

It will not affect, but you run the risk of clashing versions, especially considering `ppa:nginx/development` is the development branch.